# Bind List<Object> to datagridview and show sub objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a List orderLine. In OrderLine class I have Item item. in Item class I have Category category. 
I want to bind this orderline object to dataGridView. How can I show the item.ItemName and item.Category.categoryName ?

```
public class OrderLine()
{
    public int lineId { get; set; }
    public Item item  { get; set; }
}

public class Item()
{
    public int itemId  { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
}

public class Category()
{
    public int catId { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
}

List<OrderLine> orderLine = getOrderLineByOrderId(orderId);
dataGridView1.DataSource = orderLine;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "LineId";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "LineId";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Line ID";

dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "ItemName";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ItemName";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Item Name";

dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Category";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Category";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Category";
```

Comment: Your classes are not valid c#. The property names you put into the data grid view are different from the property names in your classes. And there is no link between `OrderLine` and `Category` in the code you posted here.

Comment: they are there in the datagridview just to show where I want them. and if you are kind show me how to show my itemName and item.Category.categoryName in the datagridview

Comment: Upvote to @gnud comment. You can directly assign list to dataGridview.DataSource = yourList; Only you need generate a list you wants to bind with grid. In above example list is not as you are expecting to bind with grid.

Comment: @D.J as OOP we work with classes inside other classes right ? then Tell me what would I do in this list of mine ?

Comment: First thing highlighted by @gund your orderline class do not have any link to Category class.

Comment: My OrderLine class has a property Item class, My item class has a property Category class. is there a way to show them in my gridview ?